# PHP SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET explained

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on modifying an existing application which uses the constant `SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET`is used A LOT. I have never encountered this before and the closest search I can get for 'SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET' is in PHP Docs for the `timezone_offset_get()` function

Here is an example of a query where `SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET has been used

```
$sql = "select s.weekNum, count(s.gameID) as gamesTotal,";
$sql .= " min(gameDateTime) as firstGameTime,";
$sql .= " (select gameDateTime from schedule where weekNum = s.weekNum and DATE_FORMAT(gameDateTime, '%W') = 'Thursday' order by gameDateTime limit 1) as cutoffTime,";
$sql .= " (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR) > (select gameDateTime from schedule where weekNum = s.weekNum and DATE_FORMAT(gameDateTime, '%W') = 'Sunday' order by gameDateTime limit 1)) as expired ";
$sql .= "from schedule s ";
$sql .= "group by s.weekNum ";
$sql .= "order by s.weekNum;";
```

Here is my attempt to changing it

`//only adding $SQL row I changed  which I changed from above code`

```
$sql .= " (DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL " . date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane') . ") > (select gameDateTime from schedule where weekNum = s.weekNum and DATE_FORMAT(gameTimeEastern, '%W') = 'Sunday' order by gameTimeEastern limit 1)) as expired ";
```

The above query results in an error message simply stating you have an error in your sql syntx near `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane') . ") >`

**Question(s)**

1. What exactly is the purpose of `SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET` in the context above?
2. How can I edit the query `SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET` to accept `date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane')` obviously my attempt was unsuccessful, any pointers where I went wrong?
3. Is there a possible mysql statment alternative to `SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET` I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INTERVAL " . SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET . " HOUR)
```

You can simply provide a number there which corresponds to the difference in hours between server time and the time you expect to see.

```
INTERVAL 5 HOUR
         ^
```

Since you know both time zones you can easily tell that number.  Please note that a timezone set for PHP does not necessarily mean MySQL will have the same timezone. If your MySQL server uses the same timezone as your application expects you can simply remove the interval clause from your query

`SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET` is an application level constant being used in that very application and represents nothing more than a Number from the looks of it. That number you can adjust yourself based on the difference as explained before.

You don't necessarily have to go change all the queries that use that constant. In your PHP configuration file you can just define the constant value once and your queries will pick it from there.

```
define("SERVER_TIMEZONE_OFFSET",6);  // Or any number you see fit
```

Comment: Thank you will give it a go now and give feedback